# Computed CSS font family defies me

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, compass-sass

I have a rails project I am using bootstrap+compass on.

The default font family is:

> "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif

However my fonts are displaying in **Times**.

If you look at this screenshot taken from the "computed style" section in Chrome you can see that *yes*, it sees that as my font-family but is rendering *Times* anyways. Which isn't even a san-serif font, so the only way I can possibly imagine in which this would be the case is if I had no sans-serif fonts in my computer at all. *Which is not the case!*

[image]

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: I think we need some more information. What does your CSS look like?

Comment: Have you tried removing the "Helvetica Neue" and just using `Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif`? When I ran an edge build of Chromium on Linux I sometimes had this issue with the browser misinterpreting multi-word fonts....

Comment: OK so it looks like the font-family which was being set by bootstrap was then being reset by compass. I still understand why the computed styles would say that though. But removing compass fixes it.

Comment: Just outta curiosity, are you absolutely sure you didn't accidentally inspect a **parent** of the element that was in Times?